# Can't find out how to remove 'undefined' at the end of the output

Tags: javascript, console.log

Bascically the exercise expects me to do sort the charactes of a string to vowels first and then  the consonants

Sample Input

```
javascriptloops
```

Sample Output

```
a
a
i
o
o
j
v
s
c
r
p
t
l
p
s
```

Here is the function I tried :

```
function vowelsAndConsonants(s) {
  let vowel = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i] === "a" || s[i] === "e" || s[i] === "i" || s[i] === "o" || s[i] === "u") {
      vowel += s[i] + "\n";
    } 
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < s.length -1 ; i++) {
    if (s[i] !== "a" && s[i] !== "e" && s[i] !== "i" && s[i] !== "o" && s[i] !== "u") {
      vowel += s[i] + "\n";
    } 
  }
  for (let i = s.length -1; i<= s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i] !== "a" && s[i] !== "e" && s[i] !== "i" && s[i] !== "o" && s[i] !== "u") {
        vowel += s[i] ;
      } 
  }  
  console.log(vowel)
}
```

The output of `vowelsAndConsonants('javascriptloops')` is:

```
a
a
i
o
o
j
v
s
c
r
p
t
l
p
sundefined
```

How do I get rid of this 'undefined' ? I know it comes from the `console.log` but they want me to print the output with it. Thank you !

Comment: change the `i<= s.length;` to `i< s.length;`

Comment: @Pointy yes but not really the case here.

Comment: @Tibebes.M omg thank you, can you tell me why it was that the problem ?

Comment: @YoëlZerbib `s[s.length]` is `undefined`

Comment: @YoëlZerbib because this string: "x" returns a length of 1, but "x" at position 1 is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is already provided in the comments (Need to use `<` instead of `<=`, because str[str.length] is `undefined`), but I would like to propose a more readable code for your problem:

```js
const vowFirst = (input) => {
    const arr = input.split(''); // Create an array from the string, to loop it easier
    const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']; // Also create an array from the chars you want to treat differently

    return [
        ...arr.filter(char => vowels.includes(char)), // get an array of all the chars in the original array that are vowels (in order)
        ...arr.filter(char => !vowels.includes(char)) // get an array of all the chars in the original array that are NOT vowels (in order)
    ].join('\n'); // join the array back to a string (with \n)
}

console.log(vowFirst('javascriptloops'));
```

I suggest you to read into array functions on [Mozilla Devs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) as they can make your code quite a lot more readable and are also easier to handle than manual loops or similar.

Also, I would suggest you to check out the basics of JS on the same page I linked (like the [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) used in my example).